# Wordpress Shopping Cart (Custom)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, e-commerce

I am thinking of developing a shopping cart for Wordpress. I know there are existing ones out there already, but I am interested in doing my own. Wondering if it is wise to store products as a custom post, and store product options, such as price, variations, etc, as post meta. I feel it is better to use WP tables rather then creating your own.

Anyone have any suggestions or concerns with the idea?

Comment: I guess that would work ok: make a "Products" page type, don't show it in the admin section (which would confuse users), keep the content empty. I suppose you could use the wp_options table to keep track of each (user|session)'s shopping cart, tracking, history etc. If it was me, I'd rather create my own table than plonk heaps of stuff into wp_options... that table is an abomination if you ask me :)

Comment: @smcphill, feel free to post your answer as an answer... :)

Comment: Well I thought to use custom post types for products, orders, carts, etc. And then just use the WP UI to manage all of these, but under one custom tab. Users table with a custom role/caps for shop users, postmeta for different options.

Comment: @nathan, nah its right - not really a question being asked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've seen it done both ways.  i suppose it really just comes down to personal preference.  are you more comfortable with the EAV database design pattern, which is what wordpress uses, or a more standard and normalized structure.